# SQL Count with Joins return duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server

Noob query here, trying to get the unique counts where some condition is met in a sub table, example below:

```
select distinct wi.* 
from wf.WorkflowInstance wi 
inner join wf.WorkflowInstanceDocument wid on wid.WorkflowInstanceId = wi.Id
where wid.ReceivedDateTime between '1/1/2020' and '1/30/2020'
```

This works great, I get the unique records. However what I really want is a count, so I have the following which now gives me duplicates for however many more 'documents' there are in the sub table.

```
select distinct count(*) 
from wf.WorkflowInstance wi 
inner join wf.WorkflowInstanceDocument wid on wid.WorkflowInstanceId = wi.Id
where wid.ReceivedDateTime between '1/1/2020' and '1/30/2020'
```

I suppose `count(wi.*)` is what would do it, but the syntax doesn't work, maybe there's a different way to join/query/group this to give me what I want. Any help would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Use ISO format in the dates.

Comment: What about count(distinct wi.*)?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the most effective method is to use `exists`:

```
select count(*)
from wf.WorkflowInstance wi 
where exists (select 1
              from wf.WorkflowInstanceDocument wid 
              where wid.WorkflowInstanceId = wi.Id and
                    wid.ReceivedDateTime >= '2020-01-01 and
                    wid.ReceivedDateTime < '2020-01-31 
             );
```

This makes the (very reasonable) assumption that the duplicates are created by the `join`.  Why bother creating duplicate records if you are only going to expend more effort to remove them?

Also notice that I changed the date comparisons a bit.  First, this uses standard format for the date constant.  Second, instead of `between` it uses `>=` and `<`.  This ensures that the logic is correct even when there is a time component.

Answer (score -1):

`COUNT(DISTINCT fields)` is really what you want, but you can also do this with a [Common Table Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) - a temporary query result that can be used by the next statement that follows.

```
WITH cte AS
(
select distinct wi.* from wf.WorkflowInstance wi 
inner join wf.WorkflowInstanceDocument wid on wid.WorkflowInstanceId = wi.Id
where wid.ReceivedDateTime between '1/1/2020' and '1/30/2020'
)
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cte
```

You can also do this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (select distinct wi.* from wf.WorkflowInstance wi 
inner join wf.WorkflowInstanceDocument wid on wid.WorkflowInstanceId = wi.Id
where wid.ReceivedDateTime between '1/1/2020' and '1/30/2020') x
```